# SSL on certain pages only?

Tags: ssl

I've been reading around and the responses are vague:

"You can call pages as per your wish like with http:// OR with https://."

I've also heard that SSL slows down the site a tad, so using it only for certain pages on your site is vital. If I enable it on my server and I'm calling the normal http version, doesn't it automatically route to the https version?

Comment: This question has been asked a dozen of times here (despite the fact that it's offtopic for StackOverflow).

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use mod_rewrite to redirect pages that you'd like to be secure to https.  In your apache configuration, you'd leave the http as default, then edit your .htaccess file with something like the following.

```
RewriteRule ^secure.html$  https://www.yoursite.com/secure.html [R=301,NC,L]
```